# My GCP project is automatically creating storage buckets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have deployed a node.js API on Google App Engine which uses cloud storage for storing files. I had created a bucket, which bore the title as `<my-project-id>.appspot.com`. After a few days I have come to realize that there are 2 more storage buckets which were created without my knowledge, with the titles: `staging.<my-project-id>.appspot.com` and `<zone-name>.artifacts.<my-project-id>.appspot.com`. Why are these buckets getting created? Are those meant for backups? Am I being charged for those?

Comment: Those buckets are used by Google for services such as App Engine, Container Registgry and Cloud Build. This is covered in the documentation. Yes, you are charged for them. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These buckets are created when you deploy an app on GAE.

The bucket named **staging.project-id.appspot.com** is created for **temporary storage** when GAE deploys new versions of your app. This bucket is only available for the App Engine use - apps can't interact with this bucket.

The bucket **zone.artifacts.project-id.appspot.com** comes from the Container Registry and stores the **container images** pushed to a registry.

Regarding the pricing - GCS [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) usage limits apply to these buckets as well.

Comment: The "always free" pricing only applies to buckets in certain regions.  If the buckets are automatically created multi-region, it will not be free, and you will be charged (this happened to me).

Comment: @DougStevenson Is it possible to configure not to create multi-region buckets?

Comment: Multi region buckets are suddenly incurring charges for my free project. I also need to find a way for these buckets to stop being multi-region

Comment: I wrote about this here 
https://amiaudible.medium.com/google-cloud-app-engine-forced-charges-8b2efc06f137?source=friends_link&sk=5d32a73fa6067a31256f920b2807d936