# My GCP project automatically created 2 storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My Gcp project name is `Mobisium`. I found out that there are 2 bucket auto created in the storage browser named `mobisum-bucket` and `mobisium-daisy-bkt-asia`.I have never used bucket in the project. `mobisium-bucket` bucket is empty and the `mobisium-daisy-bkt-asia` contains one file called daisy.log. Both buckets are Location Type: Multi-region. I read in a [stack overflow question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082741/my-gcp-project-is-automatically-creating-storage-buckets) comments that If bucket are created automatically multi-region, you will be charged.
My questions is:

- Am I being charged for this buckets.
- Are these buckets required, If not should I delete them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) you are charged for:

- data storage
- network
- operations

So you will be charged for them if they contain data. You can also view all charges assosciated with your [billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history) account

This buckets names suggests that some services created them - the buckets name is hard to figure out which services. Sometimes when you turn on the services, they create buckets for themselves.

Creating new project, there shouldn't be any buckets, so if this is really new project (created from scratch) you could try to delete them.

If this will be repeated for another project (nor only for this one) it will be good idea to contact support, because this is not normal action.